# Почему блок emb2 не встаёт в одну линию с блоком knopka?

Tags: html, css

```css
.osnova {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 333px;
  background: url(ofice.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 333px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav:hover {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 333px;
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url(pen.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  color: #F08080;
}

.t2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav button {
  max-width: 220px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #F08080;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #F08080;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 83px;
  display: inline-block;
}


}
.emb2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="osnova">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <p class="t2"><b>UXPin is used by the <br><span>best designers</span> on the <i>planet</i></b>.</p>
    <div class="knopka"> <button type="button"><b>JOIN THEM</b></button></div>
    <div class="emb2"><b>UXPin</b></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Блоки находятся в разных div
2. Лишняя } в CSS
3. В CSS display: inline

```css
.osnova {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 333px;
  background: url(ofice.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 333px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav:hover {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 333px;
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url(pen.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  color: #F08080;
}

.t2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav button {
  max-width: 220px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #F08080;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #F08080;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 83px;
  display: inline;
}

.emb2 {
  max-width: 220px;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="osnova">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <p class="t2"><b>UXPin is used by the <br><span>best designers</span> on the <i>planet</i></b>.</p>
    <div class="knopka"> <button type="button"><b>JOIN THEM</b></button>
      <div class="emb2"><b>UXPin</b></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```